# Unexpected results in query with rownum condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have found old query in application that behaves unexpectally after Oracle update. I have found out that problematic part of this query is condition:

```
rownum >= 1
```

When I apply this condition, resultset contains 0 rows, otherwise it returns 1 row (which is same in older version of Oracle).

If I change condition to `rownum = 1` it returns one row. It also returns one row for `AND(rownum > 1 OR rownum = 1)` and oddly for `AND(rownum >= 1 OR rownum >= 1)`

How is it possible?

EDIT, added SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
  NI_TABLE ni
LEFT JOIN NI_TO_BOPER nibo
ON
  ni.ni_id     = nibo.ni_id
AND ni.company = nibo.company
LEFT JOIN CHOPER co
ON
  nibo.operation_id = co.operation_id
AND nibo.company    = co.company
WHERE
  (
    ni.IDENTITY_NUMBER  = '123456789'
  OR co.IDENTITY_NUMBER = '123456789'
  )
AND NI.company   ='K'
AND rownum >= 1
AND 200 >= rownum
AND ni.NI_TYPE   ='PRIV'
ORDER BY
  ni.identityNo;
```

Note I haven't created this code, so I changed names for security reasons.

Comment: If you can reproduce it with a simpler example, you should probably file a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  If the intention is to grab the first n rows, and you're now on Oracle 12c, you can take advantage of "FETCH FIRST n ROWS". https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example query that illustrates the problem?  I'm not able to reproduce it with dummy tables . Condition  `rownum>=1` should not filter anything. Are you sure you actually have `>=`,  not greater  `>`?. That would explain empty resultset - according to docs, "Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false" .

Comment: I am aware of that new function, but thank you anyway... I am just curious why that query behaves so strange... Yes, I am sure that condition is `>=` and I have read that in manual too (before I have posted this question).

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocolumn `rownum` is assigned AFTER all the result rows from the query are retrieved, and so the correct way using `rownum` to get say 10 rows, is to use `<=` as pointed out in the comments.  The rownum can **never** be greater than the number of rows returned.  Example:

```
SYS@ecs03> select table_name from dba_tables where rownum <= 10;

TABLE_NAME
--------------------------------
CCOL$
FILE$
CLU$
SEG$
ICOL$
OBJ$
TAB$
CON$
UNDO$
TS$

10 rows selected.

SYS@ecs03>
```

And better yet as Kevin pointed out, use `FETCH FIRST *n* ROWS` clause, as you can add [additional parameters to get deterministic results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA).

> For consistent results, specify the order_by_clause to ensure a deterministic sort order.

That old code may have worked years ago, but not in the last several years. I got bit on an upgrade from Oracle 9i to 10c when we assumed that `group by` implied `ORDER BY` by the same columns in the `group by` clause.  Wrong!

Comment: Never say never, but I’ve used Oracle since 7.3 and ROWNUM has always been assigned as rows are retrieved and `ROWNUM > n` has always returned zero rows.